# MongoDB: Fail when I tried to start a mongos

Tags: json, mongodb, sharding

I have started two mongod processes for a shard server and a config server, here are the commands:

```
mongod --shardsvr --dbpath \data\a1\ --port 27018 --logpath \data\logs\loga1.a1
```

and

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath \data\configdb\ --port 27019 --logpath \data\logs\log-config.a1
```

When I tried to run a mongos I got an error:

> C:\mongodb\bin>mongos --configdb CTLDBADEL18:27019
>   2014-11-10T14:00:03.662-0600 warning: running with 1 config server
>   should be done only for testing purposes and is not recommended for
>   production 2014-11-10T14:00:03.671-0600 [mongosMain] MongoS version
>   2.6.4 starting: pid=5688 port=27017 64-bit host=CTLDBADEL18 (--help for usage) 2014-11-10T14:00:03.672-0600 [mongosMain] db version v2.6.4
>   2014-11-10T14:00:03.672-0600 [mongosMain] git version:
>   3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910 2014-11-10T14:00:03.672-0600
>   [mongosMain] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6,
>   minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1')
>   BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49 2014-11-10T14:00:03.673-0600 [mongosMain]
>   allocator: system 2014-11-10T14:00:03.673-0600 [mongosMain] options: {
>   sharding: { configDB: "CTLDBADEL18:27019" } }
>   2014-11-10T14:00:03.688-0600 [mongosMain] creating WriteBackListener
>   for: CTLDBADEL18:27019 serverID: 000000000000000000000000
>   2014-11-10T14:00:03.706-0600 [mongosMain] scoped connection to
>   CTLDBADEL18:27019 not being returned to the pool
>   2014-11-10T14:00:03.707-0600 [mongosMain] ERROR: listen(): bind()
>   failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket:
>   0.0.0.0:27017 2014-11-10T14:00:03.707-0600 [Balancer] about to contact config servers and shards 2014-11-10T14:00:03.708-0600 [mongosMain]
>   dbexit:  rc:48

Can you help me and see what I am doing wrong? I have tried with different names and commands:

```
>mongos --port 27017 --configdb CTLDBADEL18:27019

>mongos --configdb CTLDBADEL18:27019 --port 27017

>mongos --configdb 10.11.82.103:27019 --port 27017

>mongos --configdb 10.11.82.103:27019
```

Answer (score 5):

Start mongos on a different  than port 27017:

```
mongos --port 27077 --configdb CTLDBADEL18:27019
```

Or alternatively, check the process that is using port 27017 and kill it, then start mongos with port 27017.

In Windows you can use **Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Resource Monitor** (or Run **resmon.exe**) and select tab '**Network**' and click on '**Listening Ports**' to check the process using 27017

Comment: How to find the mongodb process and kill it:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37954282/404699