# Failed to set up sockets during startup. dbexit: rc: 48 error in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I updated mongo to version 3.2 now I am getting this error. Earlier I was not getting error. Only after updating mongo I am getting this error. I even tried to stop and start the mongod service again but still it is showing the same error.

```
rahul ~ $ mongod
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6630 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=rahulcomp24-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-10T23:39:51.696+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-10T23:39:51.717+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-01-10T23:39:51.717+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2016-01-10T23:39:51.717+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-01-10T23:39:51.717+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

`

```
rahul ~ $ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-01-10T23:38:16.095+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if db in running, run:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

locate the db (ex. here is 77071) and kill it, run:

```
kill -9 77071
```

Answer (score 5):

Find the process running on port 27017:

```
C:\Users\hughes> netstat -aon | findstr 27017
  TCP    0.0.0.0:27017          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3344
```

The last column shows the PID (3344). Find the process name for that PID:

```
C:\Users\hughes> tasklist /fi "pid eq 3344"
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
VirtualBox.exe                3344 Console                    1    101,908 K
```

For me it turned out that VirtualBox's port forwarding was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

so the mongod output tells

```
listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017"
```

which means some process is already using the same socet. For instance, if I try to run mongod when its already running, I get exactly this output. Are you sure that this is not your case? I would guess so, as the mongo shell seems to connect successfully...

Comment: Yes i m sure I m not running any other mongod service in parallel