# Mongodb not starting. Failed to set up sockets during startup. dbexit: rc: 48 error

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu

After installing mongodb I was trying to start it for the first time running the command "mongod" on my ubuntu 16.04 terminal. I get this very same error: 
[Failed to set up sockets during startup. dbexit: rc: 48 error in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709062/failed-to-set-up-sockets-during-startup-dbexit-rc-48-error-in-mongodb)
The problem is that when I look for the processes in port "27017" it seems as mongod was already listening there (i.e. there is no other process using this port) See the image below: 
[This are the processes running in my computer, mongod in port 27017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i73Vp.png)
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the default port number for MongoDB and the error disappeared.